# Tumblr: PostSummary Outputs HTML Codes

Tags: tumblr

When I am trying to use these lines:

```
{block:PostSummary}
  {PostSummary}
{/block:PostSummary}
```

I got HTML codes, not an excerpted pure text!

It's a big problem on Title and Meta:Description elements.

What should I do?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a a look at http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#variable-transformations

> By prefixing variables with special transformation keywords, Tumblr will output variables in specialized formats — useful when passing data to Javascript, etc.
>
> > […]
> >     **`Plaintext`**
> >     Prefix any theme variable with `Plaintext` to output the string with HTML-tags stripped and appropriate characters converted to HTML-entities so they’re safe to include in HTML attributes, etc..

So it'd probably look like:

```
{block:PostSummary}
  {PlaintextPostSummary}
{/block:PostSummary}
```